Onvif Advance Security
Im trying to enable the advanvce security feature in onvif using gsoap. for that i need wsse plugin.
im using gsoap version 2.8.134
when i try to include the "wsseapi.h" in server and compile it with "wsseapi.c" im getting multipl error like the following
error:

n file included from wsseapi.c:2326:
wsseapi.h:251:67: error: use of enum ‘wsse__FaultcodeEnum’ without previous declaration
  251 | SOAP_FMAC1 int SOAP_FMAC2 soap_wsse_fault(struct soap *soap, enum wsse__FaultcodeEnum fault, const char *detail);
      |                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
wsseapi.h:269:78: error: ‘_ds__Signature’ has not been declared
  269 | SOAP_FMAC1 int SOAP_FMAC2 soap_wsse_verify_with_signature(struct soap *soap, _ds__Signature *signature);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
wsseapi.c:2421:24: error: ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsse’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa’?
 2421 | const char *wsse_URI = SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsse;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa
wsseapi.c:2422:23: error: ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsu’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa’?
 2422 | const char *wsu_URI = SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsu;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                       SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa
wsseapi.c:2423:25: error: ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_saml1’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa’?
 2423 | const char *saml1_URI = SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_saml1;
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa
wsseapi.c:2424:25: error: ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_saml2’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa’?
 2424 | const char *saml2_URI = SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_saml2;
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         SOAP_NAMESPACE_OF_wsa
wsseapi.c: In function ‘_wsse__Security* soap_wsse_add_Security(soap*)’:
wsseapi.c:2506:22: error: ‘struct SOAP_ENV__Header’ has no member named ‘wsse__Security’
 2506 |   if (!soap->header->wsse__Security)
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
wsseapi.c:2508:19: error: ‘struct SOAP_ENV__Header’ has no member named ‘wsse__Security’
 2508 |     soap->header->wsse__Security = (_wsse__Security*)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(_wsse__Security));

could some one tell how to solve this error? also i would appreciate if some one tell me the steps to build the onvif server with ws security support.
